# svg file with javascript executes only when called directly

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I have an SVG file that contains a javascript code.

This is my SVG file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
    <!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
     
 <svg version="1.1" baseProfile="full" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <polygon id="triangle" points="0,0 0,50 50,0" fill="#009900" stroke="#004400"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    alert('running js');
    </script>
 </svg>
```

The alert function executes whenever I call it directly that is "http://localhost/temp.svg".

An alert message saying running js pops up once the file is received on the browser. But if I call the same file from an IMG tag in an HTML file (http://localhost/index.html), the javascript doesn't execute.

What should I do to execute the js on the image even on the HTML file?

Comment: Please read this: [Using SVG](https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/) _The problem with both <img> and background-image… Is that you don’t get to control the innards of the SVG with CSS_ [or javaScript] _like you can with the following two ways_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<script>` will not get executed if you're using an `img` tag. This is because doing so would lead to massive security vulnerabilities in the form of XSS (cross-site scripting) attacks, allowing arbitrary code execution in image files.

Consider the Facebook news feed for example. If you could upload a SVG, whenever that SVG were displayed on another users feed you could have access to ***all*** data on that page via script in your malicious svg.

[You can read more about that here](https://medium.com/axdb/stored-cross-site-scripting-attacks-using-crafted-svg-images-1b09c9e727e4).

If you need to display the SVG on another page, your best bet would be to use an `iframe` to embed the `svg` file directly.

This would at least allow you to run the scripts for a page the user was visiting.

```
  <body>
    <iframe src="src/image.svg" >
  </body>
```

[Example in codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/svg-javascript-execution-ovvqt)

Comment: Thanks for answering. I appreciate that you gave a valid solution to my problem, but I am not trying to execute the script along IMG. I just want to understand how the IMG tag works in the behind. why does the execution of javascript inside the SVG stops when rendered inside an IMG tag.

Comment: Because the code that parses the IMG tag will not execute script; if it did every 10 year old hacker would have a field day.

Comment: I've updated my answer for additional context, but to be fair the question you asked is "What should I do to execute the js on the image even on the HTML file?"